# Recording video and audio with external input to computer with Canon 600D

Tags: video, dslr, canon, sync, audio-recording

I like to do drum covers, but the process always takes ages. I have to record my sounds from my electronic drumset (TD-9KX) to Cubase via a Tascam US122-MKii interface. Video is captured with a Canon 600D. Afterwards I have to export the audio from Cubase and insert it in Adobe Premiere together with the video and make sure both are in sync. That takes a loooooooong while!

Because the 600D has an "external mic" input that supports stereo, I thought it might be very well possible to record from my external drumset, to the interface and via its output to the 600D to the PC. This would mean that everything is in sync. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

It should be.  You might end up with impedance mismatches that have to be dealt with, so it might take a few other (relatively cheap) steps to get there (devices called pads, which bring down the level), but it should work.  The quality might not be quite as good though.

Comment: Why would the quality be worse? I suppose you are talking about the audio quality.

Comment: @BramVanroy - it depends on what the quality of the analog to digital converter in the camera is vs the quality of the audio interface you are using.  If you are actually capturing as Midi data, then it would be lossless.  Also, if there is an impedance mismatch, then the quality will deteriorate compared to not having a mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that should work. Be sure you adjust your interface for the lowest latency without audio dropouts. You will need to measure and compensate for the latency in your audio interface.

Once you know the latency value, you can easily adjust the A/V sync in the video editor. Good luck!